# url too long for a server call, error 414

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a call to the server concentrating more than 900 calls in one, only I get as status code 414.

I then tried to see what was the maximum number of requests I could make:

```
for i in range(30):
    metricaI = jsoncalc["metrics"][i]["metricId"]
    ListaMetriche.append(metricaI)
    metricURL += 'builtin:billing.ddu.metrics.byMetric:filter(and(or(eq("Metric Key","{}")))):splitBy("Metric Key"):sort(value(auto,descending)),'.format(metricaI)
metricURL = metricURL[0:-1]
```

below I execute the call to the server:

```
value = requests.get('url I cannot show?metricSelector={}&resolution=Inf&from=2022-12-01 00:00:00&to=2022-12-14 16:13:00'.format(metricURL),
                    headers={'accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            'Authorization': 'Api-Token ...'},
                    verify=False
                    )
```

Comment: Have you looked up what the HTTP 414 code means?  How long of a URL are you using?

Comment: 414 code stands for url too long, still does not solve the problem

Comment: And how long is the URL you're using?  How long of a URL does the server allow?  What part of the error is not clear to you?  What specifically are you asking?  If you're asking how to solve the problem, it sounds like the solution is to use a shorter URL.